# Как перебрать несколько массивов и собрать в один?

Tags: php

Как мне сгенерировать `$i`, чтобы первый `foreach` заполнил `$artRows` в таком виде:
`array(1 => array(2, 'id1', 'title1'),
       2 => array(2, 'id2', 'title2'),
       3 => ...);`
А второй `foreach` по такому же типу, только его первая итерация должна продолжить счет $i, те как бы в конец начать добавлять элементы.

```
            $artRows = array();
            foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
                $artRows[$i]['tbl'] = 2;
                $artRows[$i]['id'] = $row2['id'];
                $artRows[$i]['title'] = $row2['title'];
            }

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $artRows[$i]['tbl'] = 1;
                $artRows[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
                $artRows[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
            }
```

Comment: Не до конца ясно где у Вас проблемы. Более важно зачем все это. Может быть эти все елементы можно хранить в одном масиве с одинаковыми ключами. `(1 => ['id' = 1, 'title' = '1'], 2 => ['id' = 2, 'title' = '2']);`

Comment: Ну сделайте счетчик, который будет внутри первого цикла прибавляться, а потом во втором цикле его примените...... а вообще можно в одном цикле все сделать через `for` где в один массив будет добавляться с индексом `$i`, а в другой `$i + count($arr1) - 1;` Хотя уверен можно еще что-то проще сделать, в зависимости от задачи....уверен костыль сооружаете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаете переменную $i с нужным Вам первым ключем массива и инкрементируете ее в конце циклов.

```
$artRows = array();
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
             $artRows[$i]['tbl'] = 2;
             $artRows[$i]['id'] = $row2['id'];
             $artRows[$i]['title'] = $row2['title'];
             $i++;     
    }

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
             $artRows[$i]['tbl'] = 1;
             $artRows[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
             $artRows[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
             $i++; 
    }
```

Если не обязательно пропускать заполнение нулевого ключа, то лучше всего использовать стандартную функцию php array_merge();

Answer (score -1):

```
$i = 1;
$artRows = [];
foreach ($rows2 as $row2) {
    $tmp = [ 'tbl' => 2,
             'id' => $row2['id'],
             'title' => $row2['title'] ];

    $artRows[ $i++ ] = $tmp;
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $tmp = [ 'tbl' => 1,
             'id' => $row['id'],
             'title' => $row['title'] ];
    $artRows[ $i++ ] = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: поправил, будет начинаться с 1 а не с 0.